# mobile/android: layer transition only works when scrolled to top of page

Tags: android, css, scroll, css-transitions

I try to have a fixed position button that triggers a menu to appear animated from the bottom. If ever possible I want to use only CSS, no JQuery.

On my old Android phone (2.2) it works when the page is scrolled to top. But when I scroll a little down it does not work anymore, nothing happens.

The fixed div stays fixed (to see that I added a border), but the animation is not executed. In PC-browsers it works.

Did I oversee something obvious? Any help is much appreciated!

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show_menu() {
        document.getElementById("menu_sun").style.height = "50%";
    }
    function hide_menu() {
        document.getElementById("menu_sun").style.height = "0";
    }
</script>
<style>
    html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    #wrapper {
        position: relative;
        min-height:100%; height: auto !important; height:100%;
    }
    #menu_wrapper {
        position: fixed; top: 0;
        height: 500px; width: 100%;
        -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
        border: 2px solid red;
    }
    #menu_sun {
        width: 200px; height: 0;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: #FF4E0E;
        overflow: hidden;
        -webkit-transition: height 2s linear;
        -moz-transition: height 2s linear;
        -o-transition: height 2s linear;
        transition: height 2s linear;
    }
</style>
</head>

<div id="wrapper">
<h1>lots of text</h1>   <h1>lots of text</h1>   <h1>lots of text</h1>
<h1>lots of text</h1>   <h1>lots of text</h1>   <h1>lots of text</h1>
<h1>lots of text</h1>   <h1>lots of text</h1>   <h1>lots of text</h1>
<h1>lots of text</h1>   <h1>lots of text</h1>   <h1>lots of text</h1>
<h1>lots of text</h1>   <h1>lots of text</h1>   <h1>lots of text</h1>

<div id = "menu_wrapper">
    <form>
        <input type="button" id="button1" onclick="show_menu()" value="show">
    </form>
    <div id = "menu_sun">
        <form>
            <input type="button" id="button1" onclick="hide_menu()" value="hide">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a direct solution, but an indirect one... 
The problem occurs because of the fixed div, in which the animation should run.
I now "simulate" a fixed div using position absolute, but then moving the div according to the scrolling (with the same body as in original question):

```
<style>
    #menu_wrapper {
    position: absolute; top: 0;
    height: 100%; width: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onscroll = function() {
        var layertop=window.scrollY;
        document.getElementById("menu_wrapper").style.top = layertop+"px";
    };
</script>
```

On the desktop there's no visible difference to a fixed div, on my old Android 2.2 (HTC Desire) the layer jumps back into its position after every scroll. But for my purposes that's ok, and the animation runs in every position... Oh, and I adjust the div's height on body load and on window resize...